# How to enable right click on Graph using Rshiny, and show option to download dataset used in the graph

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LUxz.png)Regarding Rhiny:

How can I enable functionality of right click on graph, show option to download dataset ?
Below is my code. My requirement is, when I right click on graph, I will get an option of "Download", and by clicking on "Download" it should download respective data set linked to that graph. (Like we do with Download Button or Download Link)

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)


City <- c('city1','city2','city3','city4')
Region <- c('Region1','Region2','Region3','Region4')
Income <- c(10,12,17,20)

City_Dataset   <- data.table(City,Income)
Region_Dataset <- data.table(Region,Income)


server <- function(input, output) {

output$City <- renderGvis({
gvisBarChart(City_Dataset,
options = list(title="City",width=600, height=500)
)
})

output$Region <- renderGvis({
gvisBarChart(Region_Dataset,
options = list(title="Region",width=600, height=500)
)
})


}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage( 
fluidRow(column(6, htmlOutput("City")),
column(6, htmlOutput("Region"))
)

))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: please share your code, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Any solution ??